# How to put borders to <li> onclick in css Tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, tabs

I have css tabs with jquery fadein effect with the help of the tutorial [here](http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/css3-jquery-folder-tabs.html).I want the css to look something like [this](http://www.armagost.com/zaccordion/#examples)
http://img.ctrlv.in.s3.amazonaws.com/img/518e3d3e07928.jpg

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/5eHXN/10/) where I have reached so far.However once the tab is clicked ,the borders of the tabs disapper,I tried applied    `border-top:solid 1px #ddd;`,but its acting as if there's no such code.Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    #tabs #current a{

   background:#f8f8f8;
    height:60px;
    position:relative;
    top:-4px;
    padding-top:4px;
    border-left-width:1px;
    color:#111;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    margin:0 0 0 -1px;
    z-index:46;
border:solid 1px #ddd;}
```

First of all, make sure your border: attribute has a style, a thickness and a color. Some of your borders in your css don;t.

Second, your problem here is your using #tabs #current a as your selector. I think you meant to use #tabs #current li.

The container for your 'button' or 'tab' at the top is an li element. You have a link inside of the li element, but adding a border to it won't help because you're really adding a border inside of the tab.

tabs li affects the tabs when they are in an 'unactivated' state. tabs current li affects the one that's currently in focus.

If you wanted to add text decoration/styling to the link in focus (the text in for the tab in this case) you would use #tabs #current a. This switch solves your border issue, but I'm not sure it helps you reach your end goal with the project. The user cannot now determine besides the change in content, which is the active tab.

Cheers!

Comment: which border did not have style,color?I tried putting it on the different selector.
still doesnt work :( http://jsfiddle.net/5eHXN/13/
  thanks anyways :)

Comment: the border in #tabs li. Changing the selector from #tabs #current a to #tabs #current li works for me. You need a #tabs #current li

Comment: Can u plz help me in bringing border left only to the 1st tab?

i have no idea why .tabs a:first-child {
       border-left:solid 1px #ddd;

}
.tabs li:first-child {
     border-left:solid 1px #ddd;

} is not working

http://jsfiddle.net/5eHXN/22/

Comment: You want a border left to all tabs don't you? Otherwise they won't look like buttons

Comment: No,only the 1st one.....

The "border-right" of all tabs is becoming left border for the next tab except the 1st one

Comment: `#tabs:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}` works, Though I'm sure you don't want to use black as the color.

Comment: omg,that worked,http://jsfiddle.net/5eHXN/24/ perhaps there was no need to add li ,a, after that...anyways thanks a lot